# cv2 Module not Found Even though I downloaded it

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

I am currently in PyCharm and I have the following line of code:

```
import cv2
```

Nonetheless, it gives me the error `No module named cv2`
I went to Preferences > Project Interpreter > + then found and downloaded cv2 just fine. In the Project Interpreter it lists cv2 as installed. I am not sure why it still shows that the module doesn't exist. Is there some way to download cv2 via command line. I am on OS X 10.10. 
Here is the code I have so far (all the other imports work just fine):

```
# Program for OCR

import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that sometimes after installing a module in PyCharm it requires a restart in order for it to work. Also, if you do want to do it in the command line, try `pip3 install cv2`.

Comment: That didn't work. This is the output from `pip3 install cv2`:
`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cv2 in /Users/dsiegler19/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`
And when I try `pip install --upgrade pip` it outputs:
`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Comment: And I made sure that my terminal was running python 3.

Comment: Note sure why it's giving you an `ImportError` but, as to the second part of your question, make sure you do `pip3 install --upgrade pip` otherwise it defaults to pip for python 2.7. By the error message you can see that `cv2` is indeed installed, it's just not importing for some reason.

Comment: Is there any way to check if a module is installed via the Python terminal or any way to install a module via the Python terminal (I doubt it but it doesn't hurt to ask).

Comment: @dsiegler19 Yes, doing `help("modules")` in the python console should do the trick. As for installing one, you could just mimic a call to pip in the terminal with `subprocess` like so: `subprocess.call(["pip3", "install", "cv2"])`. Or, better yet, just import `pip` and install it like this: `pip.main(["install", "cv2"])`. However, I don't see how these answers bring you any closer to solving your problem.

Comment: Both the `subprocess` and `pip.main` returned `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cv2 in /Users/dsiegler19/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages`

Comment: @dsiegler19 Yes, that was expected, you successfully installed `cv2` the first time you tried. I was merely answering your question. As to why it's still giving you an `ImportError` (is it?, try just importing `cv2` in the python console), I don't know.

Comment: When I try to import cv2 in the python console on PyCharm or just the regular Python console it gives me an import error. Maybe I have to do from something import cv2? Really pulling on strings?